# Solving nonlinear differential multi-variable equation with block-matrices

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, implicit-function-theorem, block-matrices

Here is the problem:

Given a formula $f:\mathbb{R}^{n+k}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, written as $f(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t);a1,...ak)$ with $k$ real unknown parameters $a_1,...,a_k$. For any $(a1,...ak)$, $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R^n}$. $(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$ is an unknown curve passing through $(0,0,...,0)$.$t\in\mathbb{R}$ is "time".

A constraint for $f$ is:

The formula $f(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t);a1,...ak)$ should be constantly $(0,0,...,0)$ along the curve $(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$.

I want to know about the curve $(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$. For example,when do they exist,when are they unique,or can I derive the exact curve, and many other aspects.

Here are what I am intend to do to solve the problem:

Since $f$ is constantly $(0,0,...,0)$,I calculate the $n$th derivation of $f$:

The first derivation is:

$A\cdot X'$ where $A$ is the Jacobian of $f$ and $X'$ is the column vector $(\frac{dx_1}{dt},...,\frac{dx_n}{dt})^T$.Thus,and $X'$ can be solved by the linear equation $A\cdot X'=0$.

I can get the other $n$th derivation by the law of derivation of Matrix:
(Given Matrix $S$ and $T$,$(S\cdot T)'=S'\cdot T=S\cdot T'$.)

So then the 2nd derivation is:
$A'\cdot X+A\cdot X'$,notice that $A'$ is not an exact constant matrix but contains $X'$ term.While $X'$ can derived by the linear equation $A\cdot X'=0$.

Keep doing this,a block-matrix can be derived:

$\begin{bmatrix}
 b_{11} A&0  &0  & 0 &...&0 \\
  b_{21}A'&b_{22} A &0  &0&...  &0 \\
  b_{31}A''&b_{32} A' &b_{33}A  &0&...  &0 \\
  b_{41}A^{(3)}&b_{42}A''  &b_{43}A'  &b_{44}A&...  &0 \\
  ...\\
b_{n1}A^{(n)}&b_{n2}A^{(n-1)}&&&...&0
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
X' \\
X''\\
X^{(3)}\\
 ...\\
X^{(n)}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0\\
0\\
 ...\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$

$b_{i,j}$ are constants.
Usually,Given any specific $f$,Each $X^{(i)}$ can be derived by the $i$th equation.
But is there any thing can I derive when $f$ is not specific but with parameters?Such as the existence or the uniqueness of the curve  $(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$？

Thanks ahead!